# LLVM C API: Load value behind pointer in Postgres

Tags: c, postgresql, llvm

i have been trying to wrap my brain around how I can load the value behind a C-pointer into a LLVM register.
So far, my attempts have not worked.

```
LLVMValueRef x = l_as_float8(b, LLVMBuildLoad(b, l_ptr_const((void *)arguments[0], TypeDatum), ""));
```

This is Postgres internal, so `l_as_float8` bitcasts a register to float, and `l_ptr_const` does this:

```
static inline LLVMValueRef
l_ptr_const(void *ptr, LLVMTypeRef type)
{
    LLVMValueRef c = LLVMConstInt(TypeSizeT, (uintptr_t) ptr, false);

    return LLVMConstIntToPtr(c, type);
}
```

The value of x is not yet known at the time of building the function, and therefore the only thing i know is, that it is stored at arguments[0] which is of type Datum. How do i access that?

Comment: If you want the value, you have to look at the CallInst in a caller than the Argument in the Function. The Function doesn't know the value, that's why it is an Argument. The CallInst may also just reference some other value that you can't reason about, but it may also contain a ConstantInt or something as the relevant [getArgOperand()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389).

Comment: The name was choosen badly, but those arent actually the functionarguments, they are just named this way.

Comment: I see. You're in good company, IMO the Argument class should have been called Parameter ;) I assume LLVMValueRef wraps a Value. In that case you can call dump() on it, and it'll tell you something about itself on stderr, usually something useful. It'll probably say either that it is a Datum that has been cast to Value at compile time (in which case you can cast back using C/C++ casts), or a Datum that has been cast to Value using LLVM's runtime casts (in which case you can get the original by using (the LLVM-C wrappers for) either CastInst::getOperand(0) or ConstantExpr::getOperand(0)).